# Can I access and translate the Page Setup menu in a Syncfusion report (rdl)?

Tags: .net, rdl, syncfusion

I was wondering if there is a way to access the Labels in the Page Setup menu of a Syncfusion report so I can translate them to spanish.

[Page Setup Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUjVO.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don’t have support to localize the Page Setup dialog labels in our Report Viewer. We have logged this as a feature request and it will be available in any of our upcoming release, we request you to contact support@syncfusion.com for further assistance regarding this feature.